# How can I deserialize a json dataset in .net core

Tags: c#, json, json.net, .net-core

I'm trying to fetch different items from an api, which returns a json. The problem I'm having is getting the properties from the json since it isn't always the same name. I've deserialized json files before, but they were different from this one. Here's the json I have:

```
{"2": {"name": "Cannonball", "store": 5}, "6": {"name": "Cannon base", "store": 187500}, "12289": {"name": "Mithril platelegs (t)", "store": 2600}, "8": {"name": "Cannon stand", "store": 187500}, "10": {"name": "Cannon barrels", "store": 187500}, "12": {"name": "Cannon furnace", "store": 187500}}
```

It's actually a little bigger then this, but I can't figure out how to easily deserialize it, since the id doesn't have a real name, on the documentation of newtonsoft.json I saw something about using datasets, I don't know if that'd actually work but I've seen they have been removed. I'd really love to get this working since it's kinda been bothering me for quite some time now.

If there's anyone who knows how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that an array? It's not surrounded by square brackets. Any JSON converter is going to think that is one object. It's valid JSON, but it seems like an odd result. What is the source?

Comment: @AustinWinstanley I get the json from [here](https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/names.json) it's basically a site to collect all the items from a game I play, with the ids, the problem is I need the id's which is in this case the name of the object, and the name of the items. They have one more api but the other one just contains a little more information, still has ids as object names

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can handle this situation by deserializing into a `Dictionary<string, T>` where `T` is a class to hold the item data, for example:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Store { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize like this:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hf1NPP